# I have a php script with html div content. need to fetch php with html code including css

Tags: php, html, css, file-get-contents

I have a PHP code that fetch data from another server. i can't use iframe due to SSL.

I'm tryin to use the code to fetch php content

here is the code im using:

```
$statsframe = file_get_contents('http://myurl/index.php');  
echo $statsframe;
```

the code is actually working but unfortunately the css is broken and no html showing.

Is there a way i can make the HTML with css show properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php

$fp = fsockopen('stackoverflow.com',80);

$request  = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "HOST: stackoverflow.com\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

fwrite($fp,$request);
while(!feof($fp))
  echo fgets($fp,256);

fclose($fp);
```

but you know use the [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) package, which is very simple